# Excel: Map tag based on strings (if string contains one of many strings)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table looking like:

```
| Line  | string-column   | tag-column |
| ----- | --------------- | ---------- |   
| 1     | free txt string |            |
| 2     | free txt string |            |
| 3     | free txt string |            |
| 4     | free txt string |            |
| 5     | free txt string |            |
```

What I'm trying to do is to fill in the column "TAG" a word based on the free text string in the second column.
I do have a mapping like

```
(TAG1)   -> string-column contains any/multiple of ("sting11", "string12", "string13", ...)
(TAG2)   -> string-column contains any/multiple of ("sting21", "string22", "string23", ...)
(TAG3)   -> string-column contains any/multiple of ("sting31", "string32", "string33", ...)
(TAG4)   -> string-column contains any/multiple of ("sting41", "string42", "string43", ...)
(TAG-NA) -> string-column contains none of the strings before or from multiple lines (e.g.: "string41" & "string23")
```

This is a very simple mapping and could be stores in another table if needed.
The question would be how to realize the mapping using a formula in the tag-column cells? (TAG-NA -> no string or multiple tag matches)

I currently started with:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("string11";B1;1));"Not found";"TAG1")
```

that would check for TAG1 just ONE of the possible matching strings (one of many).
If I would nest this formula 3 times I could catch all form TAG1 in the current list (but could be extended) and I would have to do it for each Tag. That would result in an unmaintainable formula.

I see I would have to find a way to:

- search if there is any of the "TAG1" strings in it at once
- nest that solution.

is there a formula-function in Excel allowing that? Or is there even a better way to map this? (without using VBA etc)

Comment: would you need ALL instances of the tag, say there were 2 matches? Or is the first tag returned enough? Maybe provide some sample data that would show what the result should look like

Comment: @Dave: thanks for the question - actually it should be always one TAG, but in case there would be a multiple matching row the last "TAG-NA" should be uses (I know there is something to look at)

Answer (score 1):

Data looks like this:

[image]

In cell C2 enter this formula:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(IF(ISBLANK($B$14:$E$17),"@@@","^"&$B$14:$E$17&"^"),"^"&SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","^ ^")&"^"),""))=0,$A$18,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(INDEX($A$14:$A$17,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(FIND(IF(ISBLANK($B$14:$E$17),"@@@","^"&$B$14:$E$17&"^"),"^"&SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","^ ^")&"^"),ROW($B$14:$B$17)-ROW($B$14)+1),ROW($A$14:$A$17)-ROW($A$14)+1)))),"")))
```

Adjust ranges as needed...

---

Explanation:

This formula uses the FIND function on an array (meaning on multiple values). If it sees a match, it returns a number from 1 to 4 (or however many tags you have minus the NA-TAG) and then uses that number to retrieve (using the INDEX function) a list of the corresponding tags, and joins them (if there are more than one match) using the TEXTJOIN function.

The reason for `@@@` is to replace blank cells like cell E14 in my example data which might return a match, so the cell becomes replaced with `@@@`, which should never return a match (unless you have "@@@" somewhere in your data, which I would bet that you don't)

The reason for adding the `^` (caret) symbols: I put the caret symbol before and after each word dynamically in the formula so that partial matches aren't found. Otherwise, if you had 'tag34' somewhere, then 'tag3' would show up as a match because it is in fact a substring of 'tag34'. However, `^tag34^` is not a match of `^tag3^`...

Comment: This solution can have multiple matches returned, if you have the TEXTJOIN function in excel, and it also allows for different amounts of strings per tag

Comment: Looks nice (does more than expected), but is there a bit explanation possible - I've to verify that that tomorrow if I really understand this.

Comment: @PaulEdison:  You said twice in your question (and a third time in a comment) that, if a string (in Column `B`) matches multiple key strings (e.g., "string41" & "string23"), then Column `C` should get `TAG-NA`.  But Dave’s answer would return all the matching tags (e.g., ``TAG4, TAG2``) and you say that it looks nice.  So, what behavior do you want?  Please clarify your question.  And, yes, providing sample data would be useful.